# MechanicalSoup Amazon Login Cookie Problems

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cookies, mechanicalsoup

I am currently trying to login to Amazon with MechanicalSoup.
I am able to open the login page but it tells me I need to enable Cookies to continue. But since the MechanicalSoup Documentation states that it would automatically store and send cookies I am at a loss on where the problem might be.

This is my current code:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(
    soup_config={'features': 'lxml'}
)

browser.session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
browser.open("https://www.amazon.de/gp/navigation/redirector.html/ref=sign-in-redirect?ie=UTF8&associationHandle=deflex&currentPageURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.de%2F%3Fref_%3Dnav_custrec_signin&pageType=Gateway&switchAccount=&yshURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.de%2Fgp%2Fyourstore%2Fhome%3Fie%3DUTF8%26ref_%3Dnav_custrec_signin")

browser.launch_browser()
```

[Amazon Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRNwW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are stored based upon domain name. One application (web site) cannot save cookies for another application (web site) unless the domain name is the same.

In your example, your application is launching a web browser for Amazon's domain. You cannot save cookies for Amazon's domain.

Solution: Enable cookies in the browser. This is Amazon's requirement.

Comment: I believe I didn't make my problem clear enough. It seems to be a prblem specific to amazon. I can login to github for example without problems, so cookies are definitely enabled. But for some reason amazon still blocks any login attempts from my application

Answer (score 0):

I tried a variant of your code and it doesn't work either:

```
>>> browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) C
hrome/61.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')                                                                                           
>>> browser.open("https://www.amazon.com/")
<Response [200]>
>>> browser.follow_link("^/gp/navigation")
<Response [404]>
```

(It does find the right link, but gets a 404 when following it)

It seems Amazon does its best to block bots, and if so you shouldn't try to write a bot (the fact that you have to fake a user-agent to access the site is a good indicator that you're doing something wrong).

Solution: do not write bots for amazon :-(.